# Where to start and what to choose for a simple gui project in c++?

Tags: c++, .net, qt, user-interface

I know this question has been answeared before, since i rad most of the answears already, but they didn't fully address what i was looking for, also i'm trying to get a heads up really really case-specific, since i need to develop an app really fast and i have almost no G.U.I. experience, so here is my problem:

I need to develop an application wich allows the input of some text fields (actually a database support-like would be awesome) and i need to store the inputs (like in a database, a .txt file could be good too if it would fasten up the developing)

once the input are fully stored (some text field must be unique) i need to pull some data from the database.

the final intention is to code a simple "random winner extractor" by simplying assigning a list of "number" to each entry and then calling the rnd function i will check who is the winner.

in addition to this i would love to be able to add a little animation to the whole gui (a gif would be enough)

Coming from vb6 Gui developing (that's the only G.U.I. developing experience i have so far) i searched from some good "drag and drop visual gui framework" and i bumped up into QT and into the .net Framework for visual c++ 2010, and i must admit i like them both, but i have no idea where can i get the Heads up to start coding in them... for example i have no idea how to change a text field value, or how to call the equivalent of "onChange" javascript handler for any of the forms (in neither the Qt or .net framework)

since i'm a little rusty with actual Event handlers and  api codes,here are my 2 questions:

1.Between .NET and QT, for the sole realization of this single application, wich will be run in a windows computer, based on the "simplicity to learn and develop" wich should i choose?

2.Given the answear for point 1, where could i get some reference or material on how to easly understand the basics? (all the tutorial i found or tried so far gives me only case specific knowledge, but they won't cover overall function i need to know, like how to display a message box, or how to interact with the object values, or how to write down the values into a file...)

Comment: I don't know about .Net. I don't use Windows much for anything except keeping my wife happy. However, [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Basic_Qt_Programming_Tutorial) is a good place to get started with Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Simplicity to learn and develop" is kinda subjective if you think about it and can rely on what you feel more comfortable with I think. I don't know much about .NET but you said you have a background in VB so maybe .NET might be the best approach for GUI development for you. If you know your way around C++ better, QT is surely the way to go, it's fast and powerful. I can't give you any reference material for .NET but you should definitely start with the [qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/) provided online. If you prefer to learn from video tutorials you can check out the [Void Realms](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63) Qt youtube tutorials. The videos target Qt 4.7 if my memory serves me correctly but alot of the stuff he teaches are still more or less applicable with the newer versions of Qt. And finally, if you look in the examples section of Qt Creator (or online as well), they are some examples that are tutorial style and they can teach you some core concepts of Qt like the signals and slots system for one.

Comment: Void Realms videos seems like a great resources, i can't really understand what i should watch out in the qt online documentation, i mean, it seems really really vague... i'm more "code sample" kind of a learner, as in i prefeer learning by actually Reading a code i don't know, understand what it does, and then make a program by myself with what i learned...
i will try the Qt Creator, i will approve this as an answear later, after i receive some feedback and i get an actual chance to check it out ^^

Comment: When I first started using Qt I had the same impression that the documentation was "vague" in a sense. But after just going through the tutorials, watching a few vids and finding other tutorials on the web I came across concepts that I wanted to know more about and that's where I started to look for exact topics in the docs. The more I did that is the more I came across interesting things and the less the docs seemed vague. Though that might not be your style of learning you can give it a shot and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is more difficult than C#. But it is more flexibel. C++ is an independent standard. C# on the other hand is safer to use.

Qt is cross platform. It can be used almost everywhere (except web applications) easily. .NET is for Microsoft and Windows only but common on that platform.

Qt is easy to learn and it is powerful. .NET is also powerful but I experienced .NET being harder to learn than Qt.

Qt is open source while .NET is closed source.

Pick the points that are important for you. I think the main question you should consider is: Do you intend to create a cross-platform application (today or in future)?

PS: Normally you should not ask such questions here since they tend to start endless discussions. The above is my personal opinion and hopefully it will be taken as subjective without the need of commenting it.

Comment: i rad most of the other answear on the subject, but none of them pointed what i needed for: some resource to start learning the 2 frameworks. i appreciate your effort, but  as i stated i need some documentation to learn how to use both of them, DanielJG sent me great resources for QT but i still lack any .NET documentation wich seems i should not need since QT seems easier and more portable :)
thanks for your answear thou, you confirmed once more time i should go for QT as others stated everywhere in Stackoverflow ^^

Answer (score 0):

"simplicity to learn and develop" is what .NET is for, especially for database apps. But to get that simplicity use VB.NET or C#, not C++.